How to multiply lines from two different text files into one text file in Python?
How to multiply lines from two different text files into one text file in Python?



file 1
file 2




zzzzzz
bbbbbb


aaaaaa
ffffff


nnnnnn
kkkkkk



I would like the result sequence to be as follows
| result |
| zzzzzzbbbbbb |
| zzzzzzffffff |
| zzzzzzkkkkkk |
| aaaaaabbbbbb |
| aaaaaaffffff |
| aaaaaakkkkkk |
| nnnnnnbbbbbb |
| nnnnnnffffff |
| nnnnnnkkkkkk |

I'm tired trying to make this code or find something similar, so many thanks to anyone who helps me with the solution.
def write_files(files):
    opened_files = []
    for f in files:
        opened_files.append(open(f, "r"))

    output_file = open("result.txt", "w")
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in opened_files[0])
    opened_files[0].seek(0,0)
    for i in range(num_lines):
        line = [of.readline().rstrip() for of in opened_files]
        line = " ".join(line)
        line += "\n"
        output_file.write(line)
    for of in opened_files:
        of.close()
    output_file.close()

write_files(["1.txt", "2.txt"])


That's called 'join' or 'concatenate', not 'multiply'.

The easy way is to use itertools.product:
import itertools

def write(files):
    data = [ open(f).read().splitlines() for f in files]
    return [''.join(t) for t in itertools.product(*data)]

print('\n'.join(write(['f1.txt','f2.txt'])))

Output:
zzzzzzbbbbbb
zzzzzzffffff
zzzzzzkkkkkk
aaaaaabbbbbb
aaaaaaffffff
aaaaaakkkkkk
nnnnnnbbbbbb
nnnnnnffffff
nnnnnnkkkkkk

Note, however, that the list grows really big very quickly.

Thanks Tim Roberts
The problem has been resolved.

@Ms if this answer solved your question, please accept it using the v-shaped button to its left. Thank you.
